# Laravel Controller

Tags: controller, laravel-4

Please I  got an error while defining a new function in my Controller:
In my Controller I have CRUD methods such as create , update , show($id), edit and so on. My problem is : I wanted to define another function to show me particular profiles(imageprofiles), but it always generates me an error and rather then it uses the method imageprofiles(), it uses always the crud method show($id). All my views are correct. Can anyone help me please??? thanks in advance!

```
 <?php

class EncodingProfilesController extends \BaseController {


    public function index()
        {
            ......}
public function imageprofiles()
    {
         $Profiles = encodingprofiles::where('type', '=', 'Video')->get();
        // show the view and pass the profile to it
        return View::make('encodingprofiles.sh')
        ->with('encodingprofiles', $Profiles);
}
 public function show($id)
 {
    // get the profile
         $Profile = encodingprofiles::find($id)->first();

        // show the view and pass the profile to it
        return View::make('encodingprofiles.show') it tells me that here is the problem  Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to a member function first() on a non-object
            ->with('encodingprofiles', $Profile);
}
```

and here is the link which redirect me to this function `<a href="{{ URL::to('encodingprofiles/imageprofiles') }}">Type</a>`

Comment: what does your `routes.php` look like?

Comment: <?php

Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
Route::resource('encodingprofiles', 'EncodingProfilesController');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use nested resources.

`Route::resource('encodingprofiles', 'EncodingProfilesController');
Route::resource('encodingprofiles.imageprofiles', 'ImageProfilesController');`

you'd treat imageprofiles as a new resource within encodingprofiles and therefore needs a new new controller.

Comment: Thank you but It doesn t work @zwacky :( still the same problem it reditrect me to the page of the function show($id)

Comment: you'd also need to call it differently with an ID `encodingprofiles/ID/imageprofiles`, as there are only imageprofiles that belong to a certain encodingprofiles. if that is not the case, you perhaps shouldn't use resources.

Comment: to get a better understanding about resource routes use the command `artisan routes`.

Answer (score 0):

This:  $Profile = encodingprofiles::find($id) will get you only one object.  Don't use the first () method. Use first only if you use  $Profile = encodingprofiles::where (condition)->get()->first();